# It's there any where to let lines in dc.js independent with each other

Tags: dc.js

This is my first time to use "dc.js", but some troubles occurred as followed.
There are 6 lines in my line chart.But each line is added to its next line,so that the value on y axis can not describe the actual value of each line except the first.It's there any where for me to let these lines independent with each other? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a line series chart in dc.js 2.0, instead of a stacked line chart.

Example here:

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/series.html

Code here:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/series.html

Docs here:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#series-chart